# Parse CSV with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file and one of the lines in it is:

```
Value1|Due Date: 01/01/2000  \|||Value5
```

Expected Result:

```
FieldName1|FieldName2             |FieldName3|Fieldname4|FieldName5

Value1    |Due Date: 01/01/2000   |          |          |Value5
```

Actual Result:

```
FieldName1|FieldName2               |FieldName3|Fieldname4|FieldName5

"Value1"  |"Due Date: 01/01/2000  |"|""        |"Value5"
```

I am reading it with the following code:
`reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = '|', doublequote = False, escapechar = '\\')`
Because of the escape character, it parses the column delimiter after the second field as part of the second field and ignores the next empty field (field3).

My code:

```
reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = '|', doublequote = False, escapechar = '\\')
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = '|', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

How should I set the reader?
Or should I remove the backslashes before reading the file? Do you have any other idea?

Comment: "and escape character \"--It sounds like you don't want ``\`` to be an escape character.

Comment: csv reader works correctly here, I don't really understand question. Consider making minimal example to reproduce issue - so many fields are not required to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define `Dialect` with `escapechar` which never appears in your file, I suggest you try using NUL for that, let `file.csv` content be

```
1|||2|||3
4|||5\|||6
7|||8|||9
```

then

```
import csv
class MyDialect(csv.Dialect):
    delimiter = '|'
    escapechar = '\x00'
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE
with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=MyDialect)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

gives output

```
['1', '', '', '2', '', '', '3']
['4', '', '', '5\\', '', '', '6']
['7', '', '', '8', '', '', '9']
```

Observe that `\` needs to be escaped to get literal `\` hence `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating it. Let the `csv` module do it's work with the minimal interference:

```
cat escape.csv
Value1|Due Date: 01/01/2000  \|||Value5

import csv

with open('escape.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    cR = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    for row in cR:
        print(row)

['Value1', 'Due Date: 01/01/2000  \\', '', '', 'Value5']

fld_names = ["FieldName1", "FieldName2", "FieldName3", "Fieldname4", "FieldName5"]
with open('out_escape.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    cW = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='|')
    cW.writerow(fld_names)
    cW.writerow(['Value1', 'Due Date: 01/01/2000  \\', '', '', 'Value5'])

cat out_escape.csv
FieldName1|FieldName2|FieldName3|Fieldname4|FieldName5
Value1|Due Date: 01/01/2000  \|||Value5
```

Answer (score -1):

#### When you type `\\` in a standard string, python stores a *single* backslash

This means that you defining the escape character to be a single backslash.
Python is therefore reading the:

```
\|
```

as an attempt to escape a "|" character, i.e. make it part of the (preceding) string, rather than a separator.

Since there is no special meaning to that, it defaults back to being interpreted as a normal "|" character: the one at the end of the date. Therefore Python is correctly running the instructions you have given it.

#### From what you are expecting, I think you want to delete the `\`

If that is the case, just replace the `\` with an empty string.

```
s = s.replace(r"\","")
```

Comment: The `\|` isn't in a string literal, it's a CSV file being parsed. String literal rules have nothing to do with it. You're answering a question the OP didn't ask.

Comment: Well, the string literal ` \\\` is in the statement setting the escape character. I believe the OP was puzzled as to why putting ` \\\` as the escape character within the python, is causing a _single_ `\\` in the CSV to be taken as an escape character.